# Whats a good estimation for error measuremets when trying to predict values inside two bands?

Tags: boosting, measurement-error, gradient

I am using gradient boosting to predict two quantiles (upper and lower). The predicted value can be above, below, or in bounds. The problem I am facing is that counting the number of values in bound compared to the total predicted values is not a good indication (since you can widen the bands enough to capture more values). Also the data being predicted is the amount being used (so over allocating with higher quantiles is bad). What I am looking for is an assessment method of how good is the choice of quantiles.

Comment: Can you clarify what would constitute "good" (how do you want to measure *goodness*?)

Comment: Sure, so predicted values should be between the upper and lower quantiles. Also, a quantile should not be too far to make the difference between each quantile and the predicted value too big.